# Is there a word for someone who sells stuff acquired for free and any particular term for this kind of practice

Tags: single-word-requests

By that i don't mean a free rider who consumes the commodity himself but rather a person who sell stuffs acquired in charity (say) and makes a profit out of it. Also, is there any term for this particular practice?

Comment: ***Scrap dealer, junk dealer,*** and ***bric-a-brac dealer*** are all in this general area, each with somewhat different connotations. Which comes closest to your intended context? And how about ***eBay recycler*** (as opposed to [***Freecycler***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freecycling))? Anyway, you haven't said exactly *how* this "someone" *acquires* the stuff - maybe he's just a ***burglar***.

Comment: **Scavenger** or **gleaner** are also possibilities.

Comment: Definitely not a burglar, you see, there are often charities which give away used (but not really scrap) everyday article for those who might need it. Some other people collect those although they don't quite need it and sell them on sales. Not a very good practice! I can't call it trading also as it doesn't involve the concerned 'collector' buying anything, but rather just taking free stuff and thus depriving others who actually might need it. I was wondering if there is any particular term for such practice.

Comment: Regarding questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning: To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of a lack of detail on the context of "obtaining things for nothing".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"Scalper"  as per second entry here (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/scalper), unless we want to be sticklers and require the part about, "when they are difficult to get."

Comment: somewhat misses the re-selling of items acquired for free.

Comment: True, @ibf.  Maybe we could say "scalper" is a close cousin? ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if it applies in the context I explained in the comments above. I came across the word arbitrage. Do you think it's broader in its usage? and perhaps arbitrager? Nevertheless I'm accepting your answer as I didn't find any single word which exactly fits.

Comment: @ Clarissa:  As per Wiki, "People who engage in arbitrage are called arbitrageurs ...such as a bank or brokerage firm. The term is mainly applied to trading in financial instruments, such as bonds, stocks, derivatives, commodities and currencies."